# ghc-mod がインストール出来ません(Arch Linux, ghc7.10)

Tags: haskell

GHC7.10.1, cabal 1.22.2 を使用して cabal install ghc-mod とすると, ExposePackageId というコンストラクタがないというようなエラーが出てインストール出来ません.
そこで調べてみたところ, ghc-mod の master ブランチを clone してきて cabal install とすれば修正されているとわかったので, そのようにしたところ ghc-mod のビルド自体には成功しました.

ところが, ghc-modi を実行すると

```
cabal-helper-wrapper: /tmp/cabal-helper19747/CabalHelper/Main.hs: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
ghc-mod: readCreateProcess: /home/hoge/.cabal/libexec/cabal-helper-wrapper "/home/hoge/workspace/haskell/ghc-mod/dist" "entrypoints" "source-dirs" "ghc-options" "ghc-src-options" "ghc-pkg-options" "ghc-merged-pkg-options" "ghc-lang-options" "--with-ghc=ghc" "--with-ghc-pkg=ghc-pkg" "--with-cabal=cabal" (exit 1): failed
```

というエラーが出てしまいます.
どのようにしたら, ghc-mod を使用することができるようになるでしょうか

Comment: [Hakyll のページ](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/faq.html) に似たエラーが書いてあり，LANG を UTF-8 を使うように設定すればよいと書かれています．`$ echo $LANG` の結果を見て，`$ export LANG=(お使いの言語).UTF-8` として試してみていただけますか